# OpenShift import docker image from JFrog Artifactory unauthorized error

Tags: openshift

We have pushed our docker image to jfrog Artifactory from TFS Build pipeline.
However when we are pulling the image from OpenShift web console we are getting a "BAD_CREDENTIAL" error

The way we are pulling the image is

Click Add to Project
Click Deploy Image
In the popup window we have specified full jfrog Artifacotry URL

"abc-docker-dev-local.xyartifactory.org.com/artifactory/abc-docker-dev-local/my-proj/abc-employeetrackingops/2.0"

Error says as Could not load image metadata...  unauthorized: BAD_CREDENTIAL

Is this any Service Account issue ?
Share some pointers

Comment: The documentation "[Allowing Pods to reference images from other secured registries
](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.5/openshift_images/managing_images/using-image-pull-secrets.html#images-allow-pods-to-reference-images-from-secure-registries_using-image-pull-secrets)" describes what needs to be done (Create Secret & link Secret). From that, what have you already done?

Comment: Hi Simon, Initially I have created the secret with type Image Stream, gave the server name of the artifactory, specifed username and API Key as credentials. Now I am able to pull the Image, However when I click deploy the deployment runs for sometime and fails with BAD_CREDENTIAL error.  THe logs show also  "Back-off pulling image"